# Number of Weeks between Parameter Dates - Group by Week - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 parameter in my stored procedure @FromDate and @ToDate, I want to work out the number of weeks between @FromDate and @ToDate, @FromDate is always a Monday while @ToDate is always a Sunday but the dates could cover weeks, months etc.

Currently I have DATEDIFF(WW, @FromDate, @ToDate)

Which returns say 4 but I would like it to return 1,2,3 and 4 in 4 rows rather than just 1 row.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got it right:

```
With T( Number ) as
(
    Select 0 as Number
        union all
    Select Number + 1
        from T
        where Number < DATEDIFF(WW, @FromDate, @ToDate)

)

SELECT NUMBER FROM T WHERE Number>0;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16805)

Comment: It will not give correct result in case the answer is 0. Answer below will handle this scenario

Comment: @RohitSingh: I've changed this query to handle this issue in case of 0 weeks it returns nothing now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely. The way the stored procedure is there will always be a minimum of 1 so the 0 weeks wouldnt come into it but will use it just to be safe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = GETUTCDATE() - 90
SET @EndDate = GETUTCDATE() 

DECLARE @WeekNumber INT

SET @WeekNumber = DATEDIFF(WW, @StartDate, @EndDate) ;

WITH    CTE_WeekNumber ( WeekNumber )

      AS ( SELECT   1
           WHERE    @WeekNumber >= 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   WeekNumber + 1
           FROM     CTE_WeekNumber
           WHERE    @WeekNumber >= WeekNumber + 1
         )

SELECT  *
FROM    CTE_WeekNumber
```